# Have issue with duplicate account number and need to limit the "LASTMEMBERACTIVITY" column to 90 days as required

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL and I need to get a 90 day report. The problem I am having is that the account number is being duplicated and the report is not limiting to the 90 days required. It is showing from March 2021 to January 2011 on LASTMEMBERACTIVITY.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT
                  A.ACCOUNTNUMBER, N.FIRST, N.MIDDLE, N.LAST, FORMAT(A.OPENDATE,'MM/dd/yyyy') AS 
                  "OPENDATE", FORMAT(A.RECORDCHANGEDATE,'MM/dd/yyyy') AS "LASTMEMBERACTIVITY",
                  L.CHARGEOFFDATE, A.CLOSEDATE, L.CHARGEOFFTYPE, A.WARNINGCODE1, A.WARNINGCODE2, 
                  A.WARNINGCODE3, A.WARNINGCODE4, A.WARNINGCODE5, A.WARNINGCODE6, A.WARNINGCODE7,
                  A.WARNINGCODE8, A.WARNINGCODE9, A.WARNINGCODE10, A.WARNINGCODE11, 
                  A.WARNINGCODE12, A.WARNINGCODE13, A.WARNINGCODE14, 
                  A.WARNINGCODE15,A.WARNINGCODE16, 
                  A.WARNINGCODE17, A.WARNINGCODE18, A.WARNINGCODE19, A.WARNINGCODE20, N.DEATHDATE
FROM     
                  ACCOUNT AS A INNER JOIN
                  LOAN AS L ON A.ACCOUNTNUMBER = L.PARENTACCOUNT INNER JOIN
                  SAVINGS AS S ON A.ACCOUNTNUMBER = S.PARENTACCOUNT INNER JOIN
                  NAME AS N ON A.ACCOUNTNUMBER = N.PARENTACCOUNT
WHERE  
                 (L.CHARGEOFFDATE IS NULL) AND (A.CLOSEDATE IS NULL) AND (N.DEATHDATE IS NULL) AND 
                 a.RECORDCHANGEDATE  < DATEADD(DAY, -90, GETDATE()) 
             
ORDER BY 
                 A.RECORDCHANGEDATE desc,  DATEADD(MONTH, -90, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]: remove all excess columns from your query, anonymize a few rows of your data and add them as a sample data into your question. Add a tag for the DBMS implementation being used and its version. Read [SQL tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your where clause to the following:

```
(L.CHARGEOFFDATE IS NULL) AND (A.CLOSEDATE IS NULL) 
AND (N.DEATHDATE IS NULL) AND 
a.RECORDCHANGEDATE > DATEADD(DAY, -90, GETDATE())
```

The issue is you are asking for all records that are older than 90 days ago.   What you actually want is all records that are greater than 90 days ago.

Comment: It is difficult to tell why duplicates based on what you have.   It is POSSIBLE that a person has both a loan and a savings account (based on your joins).    However, you never display any fields from the savings table.   Comment out the savings table and run your query.

Comment: @CarlosDiaz Aren't you disclosing a personal information now?